# Замена гласных в строке

Tags: java

Как заменить каждую первую букву слов, начинающихся с гласной буквы, на прописную? К сожалению, у меня не получается.

Comment: можете смело сбрасывать код мы найдем в чем ошибка. 

p.s. метки "учебное задание" нехватает; похожие вопросы уже были =/

Comment: в том то и дело, ничего путного не могу придумать =(

Answer (score 4):

Нашел и слегка адаптировал вот такое:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([aiueoаеёиоуыэюя])(\S*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1).toUpperCase() + m.group(2));
}
str = m.appendTail(sb).toString());
```

Вопрос про гласность английской «y» оставим открытым.

Comment: а можете мне объяснить принцип его действия?

Comment: Поиск и замена по регулярному выражению — ищем все, начинающееся на маленькую гласную букву (первая группа) и дальше как можно больше непробельных символов (вторая группа). Все что нашли — заменяем на то же самое, но с первой буквой заглавной. Поскольку строки в Java иммутабельны, то на время копаний преобразуется все в StringBuffer, потом, соответственно, назад.

Почитайте документацию на `java.util.regex`, я плохой объяснятель, увы.

Answer (score 1):

Есть одна функция, которой я пользуюсь периодически. Может и вам подойдёт. Тут мы не будем искать именно первую гласную, т.к. внутри слова буква написанная в верхнем регистре - это тоже бред. [Тут смотрим работу вживую](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/zn99P/2/).

```
function str_replace ( search, replace, subject ) {

    if(!(replace instanceof Array)){
        replace=new Array(replace);
        if(search instanceof Array){
            while(search.length>replace.length){
                replace[replace.length]=replace[0];
            }
        }
    }

    if(!(search instanceof Array))search=new Array(search);
    while(search.length>replace.length){
        replace[replace.length]='';
    }

    if(subject instanceof Array){
        for(k in subject){
            subject[k]=str_replace(search,replace,subject[k]);
        }
        return subject;
    }

    for(var k=0; k<search.length; k++){
        var i = subject.indexOf(search[k]);
        while(i>-1){
            subject = subject.replace(search[k], replace[k]);
            i = subject.indexOf(search[k],i);
        }
    }

    return subject;

}

var search = ['А','Е','Ё','И','О','У','Ы','Э','Ю','Я'];
var replace = ['а','е','ё','и','о','у','ы','э','ю','я'];
var str = 'Ананас, Анавас, Аффтар жжот, ХЗ что ЕщЁ добавить... Но Гласные заменяются нОрмАльНо';
var newStr = str_replace(search, replace, str);
alert(newStr);
```

Comment: @Deonis, это на каком языке ? TC вроде бы на Java хотел.

Comment: Сорри, не обратил сначала внимание.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: так мне вроде как только гласные с прописной надо?

Comment: я знаю... просто ты не показал, как ты делал.. создай массив гласных, проверяй слова в цикле, если первая буква совпадает с твоим массивом - пери ее и делай большой =)

Comment: FileReader fr = new FileReader("f"); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr); String s = br.readLine(); System.out.println(s); int[] A={'a','e','i','o','u','y'}; final String [] res = s.split ( "\ " );
не получается короче у меня=( сдаюсь все.